# multi-part error even though table exists

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update records from one table to another in same database. What am I doing wrong? SQLMS2017 does not like [dbo].[TempSupplier3].[addaddress]  on 4th line. I've tried alsorts from including aliases. Table definitely exists as I can choose it and drag it. Keep getting multi-part identifier cannot be bound.

```
UPDATE 
fds.Address
SET
fds.Address.addaddress = [dbo].[TempSupplier3].[addaddress] 
FROM 
 dbo.TempSupplier3 TS 
INNER JOIN 
fds.Address AS FA
    ON 
    TS.addshortname = FA.addShortName
WHERE
FA.addshortname = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you once you alias a table as something else, you need to keep using that alias.  So, try doing that:

```
UPDATE FA
SET addaddress = TS.[addaddress] 
FROM dbo.TempSupplier3 TS
INNER JOIN fds.Address AS FA
    ON TS.addshortname = FA.addShortName
WHERE
    FA.addshortname = 'yes';
```

Or, if you want to use the fully qualified table name everywhere, the use this:

```
UPDATE fds.Address
SET addaddress = dbo.TempSupplier3.[addaddress] 
FROM dbo.TempSupplier3
INNER JOIN fds.Address
    ON dbo.TempSupplier3.addshortname = fds.Address.addShortName
WHERE
    fds.Address.addshortname = 'yes';
```

Answer (score 1):

update with join syntax is will be like this... alias names should be made like this

```
 UPDATE 
FA 
SET
FA.addaddress = ts .[addaddress] 
FROM 
 dbo.TempSupplier3 TS 
INNER JOIN 
 [Address] FA 
    ON 
    TS.addshortname = FA.addShortName
WHERE
FA.addshortname = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are aliasing your tables but then not using the alias...

Change it to:

```
UPDATE FA
SET FA.addaddress = TS.[addaddress] 
FROM 
   dbo.TempSupplier3 TS 
INNER JOIN 
   fds.Address AS FA ON 
   TS.addshortname = FA.addShortName
WHERE
   FA.addshortname = 'yes'
```